# Filter groups with more than n members with `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with groups of `Sequ`ences:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = letters[1:13],
  Sequ = c(NA,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,NA,NA,4,4,4,4)
)
```

I want to filter groups that have **more than a critical number n of members**; let's suppose that critical number n is 3. This attempt only selects the 4th member row but not the `Sequ`ence as a whole:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
  filter(row_number() > 3)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
# Groups:   Sequ [1]
  ID     Sequ
  <chr> <dbl>
1 n         4
```

So how can I get this desired output, ideally with 'dplyr` but other solutions are welcome as well:

```
df
  ID Sequ
1  k    4
2  l    4
3  m    4
4  n    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code that first removes NA and then `group_by` the Sequ and `filter` groups with more than 3 members:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = letters[1:14],
  Sequ = c(NA,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,NA,NA,4,4,4, 4)
)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
  filter(n() > 3)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#> # Groups:   Sequ [1]
#>   ID     Sequ
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 k         4
#> 2 l         4
#> 3 m         4
#> 4 n         4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Old answer**

You can use the following code:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = letters[1:14],
  Sequ = c(NA,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,NA,NA,4,4,4, 4)
)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
  filter(Sequ > 3)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#> # Groups:   Sequ [1]
#>   ID     Sequ
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 k         4
#> 2 l         4
#> 3 m         4
#> 4 n         4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Note that `filter(n() > 3)` is also workable (and is more independent of type of data)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compact option with `data.table`

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)[,.SD[.N>3],Sequ]
   Sequ ID
1:    4  k
2:    4  l
3:    4  m
4:    4  n
```